# Extend a div to end of screen while keeping contents within container

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am creating a navbar that has a subnav within. I am trying to keep the contents of this subnav within a container, while extending its background beyond the container (blue).

I had thought initially of using :after to create this, but how can I place it directly beside it?

[image]

Comment: Share a jsfiddle

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One way to achieve this is by using absolute positioning for the :after pseudo-element and setting its top and left properties to position it beside the subnav container

example

```
  <ul class="navbar">
    <li>
      <a href="#">Home</a>
      <ul class="subnav">
        <li><a href="#">Subnav Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Subnav Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Subnav Item 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<style>
.navbar {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.navbar li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.navbar li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.subnav {
  position: relative;
  display: none;
  background-color: blue;
}

.navbar li:hover .subnav {
  display: block;
}

.subnav:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
</style>
```

Comment: This did the trick, I was on the right track with the :after being absolute placement but I did right: 0 and couldn't get it align side by side, I had totally forgotten I could have used %s. Thanks!